# MAUI Splash Screen

Tags: .net, maui, splash-screen

I need help

Im building a maui application, **I need a splash screen as a background image.png which fits to the whole screen**, but the default behavior of MAUI be like getting my primary color as my background view and image as Foreground img

Can anyone help me with this one?

Set the single image.png as my whole splash screen

Comment: You can't do this on Android anymore

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

Comment: <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/...</item>

if i add my png file directly to this tag, will it work?

Comment: Umm it won't...

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from showing your fullscreen image immediately *after* the splash screen, but, the splash screen requirements are the splash screen requirements.